# Delphi Ms word Automation Page setup and save in windows 10

Tags: delphi, ms-word

How it possible to setup pages like legal, A4 etc  in Delphi Word automation - after  CreateOleObject('Word.Application')  and  save the delphi created word documents with a specific name in C drive .

Comment: Which Delphi and MS Word versions?

Comment: Delphi Xe10.2 and Ms office 2016

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code below will create a document with a specified papersize and save it under a specified name:

```
uses ... Word2000;

procedure TForm1.CreateDocWithPaperSize;
var
  MSWord,
  Document,
  PageSetUp: OleVariant;
  AFileName : String;
  iDocument : WordDocument;
begin
  MsWord := CreateOleObject('Word.Application');
  MsWord.Visible := True;

  Document := MSWord.Documents.Add;
  MSWord.Selection.Font.Size := 22;
  MSWord.Selection.Font.Bold := true;
  MSWord.Selection.TypeText(#13#10);

  // the following is to get the WordDocument interface 'inside' the
  //  Document variant, so that we can use code completion on
  // iDocument in the IDE to inspect its properties
  iDocument := IDispatch(Document) as WordDocument;

  PageSetUp := iDocument.PageSetup;
  PageSetUp.PaperSize := wdPaperLegal;
  MSWord.Selection.TypeText('Hello Word.');

  AFileName := 'C:\Temp\Test.Docx';
  Document.SaveAs(FileName := AFileName);
end;
```

`Word2000.Pas` is an import unit of the MS Word type library (there are other versions - see the Servers subfolder under the OCX folder in your Delphi set-up).  In it, search for

`wdPaperSize`

, which you will find declared as a `TOleEnum`.  Immediately below that you will find a list of constants that let you specify particular paper sizes.

```
{ From Word2000.Pas }
// Constants for enum WdPaperSize
type
  WdPaperSize = TOleEnum;
const
  wdPaper10x14 = $00000000;
  wdPaper11x17 = $00000001;
  wdPaperLetter = $00000002;
  wdPaperLetterSmall = $00000003;
  wdPaperLegal = $00000004;
  wdPaperExecutive = $00000005;
  wdPaperA3 = $00000006;
  wdPaperA4 = $00000007;
  wdPaperA4Small = $00000008;
  wdPaperA5 = $00000009;
  wdPaperB4 = $0000000A;
  wdPaperB5 = $0000000B;
  wdPaperCSheet = $0000000C;
  // etc
```

Comment: Thank you .I am using windows 10.   Saving to C drive   showing errors - write protected. But I can save in D or E drive: , how it possible to save in windows 10-, C drive

Comment: Where **exactly** on your C: drive?  Read about write-access permission.   Btw, this is a completely different issue than what you asked in your q.

Comment: I mean  'C:\Temp\Test.Docx'; is not possible in windows 10

Comment: Right-click C:\Temp in Explorer, select Properties and view the Security tab.  That will tell you who does, and does not, have write permission on the folder.

Comment: What is the best reference manual  or link  for delphi  ms-word automation

Comment: Imo, the best references are the MS Documentation on automating Word (google for it), the Help documents you can get at via the Developer tab of MS Word's ribbon, and Delphi import units like Word2000.Pas.